# gunicorn: Is there a better way to reload gunicorn in described situation?

Tags: django, gunicorn, salt-stack

I have a django project with gunicorn and nginx.

I'm deploying this project with saltstack

In this project, I have a `config.ini` file that django views read.

In case of nginx, I made that if `nginx.conf` changes, a state `cmd.run service nginx restart` with `- onchanges - file: nginx_conf` restarts the service.

but in case of gunicorn, I can detect the change of `config.ini`, but I don't know how to reload the gunicorn.

when gunicorn starts, I gave an option `--reload` but does this option detects change of `config.ini` not only django project's files'?

If not, what command should I use? (ex: `gunicorn reload`) ??

thank you.

ps. I saw `kill -HUP pid` but I think salt wouldn't knows gunicorn's pid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--reload` option looks for changes to the source code not config. And `--reload` shouldn't be used in production anyway.

I would either:

1) Tell gunicorn to write a pid file with `--pid /path/to/pid/file` and then get salt to kill the pid followed by a restart.

2) Get salt to run a `pkill gunicorn` followed by a restart.

Comment: It works very well, thank you! I added a state `pkill gunicorn; gunicorn --bind ~~~` with `onchanges: - file: config`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run shell commands to manage services, use `service` states.

```yaml
/path/to/nginx.conf:
  file.managed:
    # ...

/path/to/config.ini:
  file.managed:
    # ...

nginx:
  service.running:
    - enabled: true
    - watch:
      - file: /path/to/nginx.conf

django-app:
  service.running:
    - enabled: true
    - reload: true
    - watch:
      - file: /path/to/config.ini
```

You may need to create a service definition for gunicorn yourself. Here's a very basic systemd example:

```
[Unit]
Description=My django app
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/source
ExecStart=/path/to/venv/bin/python gunicorn project.wsgi:application
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```